# MS Access query to select items not in table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Windows, MS Access 2016.

I have a table where there normally are item groups with numbers n & n + 1

```
Items
  100     
  101    
  200   
  201
  300
  301
  400
  401
```

Some items might be missing:

```
Items
  100     
  200   
  201
  301
  400   
  401
```

Here I want to find items that do not have a corresponding +/- 1 difference. 
In the table above I want to find item 100 (missing 101), 301 (missing 300).
How do I write a SQL statement that select those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `mod` operator:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.items mod 100 = 0 and
       not exists (select 1 from t as t2 where t2.items = t.items + 1)
      ) or
      (t.items mod 100 = 1 and
       not exists (select 1 from t as t2 where t2.items = t.items - 1)
      )
```

Alternatively, you can use aggregation:

```
select min(items)
from t
where items mod 100 in (0, 1)
group by items / 100
having min(items) = max(items)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!